# Adding new column to csv with the same heading as an existing column, but with different data

Tags: pandas, csv, read.csv

I would like to add two new columns every time you run the code with the same titles, but with different data values that would be found from the code. I have tried doing this through pandas, though it ends up just adding to the existing column that has the same name. Doing this through csv seems promising, though I am receiving a StopIteration error.

The values in the new columns will be found through a physical test that the python script does. I can send the overall code, though it shouldn't have an effect as I have been trying to figure this out in a separate code file.

The csv should end up looking something like this:

```
| Stage Position (°) | Normalized Power | Stage Position (°) | Normalized Power |
| ------------------ | ---------------- | ------------------ | ---------------- |
| 2                  | 5.7              | 6                  | 51.3             |
| 5                  | 9.4              | 5                  | 82.1             |
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
import csv

position_list = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
output_list = [.5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, .5]
normalized_list = [.125, .25, .5, 1, .5, .25, .125]

def Add_Column(csv_filename, column_title, column_list):
    with open(csv_filename,'r') as csvinput, open(csv_filename, 'w') as csvoutput:
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        headers = next(reader)
        headers.append(column_name)
        rows = list(reader)
        for row, value in zip(rows, column_values):
            row.append(value)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(rows)
    return None
Add_Column("Test.csv", "Stage Position (°)", position_list)
```

The error that I am receiving looks like this:

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-11138aacf254> in <module>
     11         writer.writerows(rows)
     12     return None
---> 13 Add_Column("Test.csv", "Stage Position (°)", position_list)

<ipython-input-9-11138aacf254> in Add_Column(csv_filename, column_title, column_list)
      3         reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
      4         writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
----> 5         headers = next(reader)
      6         headers.append(column_name)
      7         rows = list(reader)

StopIteration:
```

(I use Jupyter Notebook if that matters at all)